# Landsat Observation Zenith and Azimuth Angles

Tags: landsat, landsat-8, azimuth, landsat-7

I am doing a project with Landsat which needs to find out 2 Landsat images of the same area for different time, have both the same observation zenith and azimuth angles. But I can not find any information about satellite observation zenith or azimuth angle of Landsat images. Any one has an idea where I can find that information?

Comment: do you have a _MTL.txt file with your data ?

Comment: yes i have, but it only provide Sun elevation and Sun azimuth, but what i need is the observation angle of satellite. Example here http://1drv.ms/1gEzZRn

Comment: I think that it is always nadir with Landsat. But I'm not 100 % sure.

Answer (score 6):

### Satellite zenith angle

Images from **Landsat 1 - 7** are **always nadir**.
In other words, their satellite zenith angle is close to 0°.

Likewise, the *_MTL.txt* you posted corresponds to a *Landsat 5* image, and so is a nadir image.

**Off-Nadir** imagery has been introduced with **Landsat 8**.

Landsat 8 images have a field [`NADIR_OFFNADIR`](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/landsat_dictionary.html#nadir_offnadir) in their *_MTL.txt* metadata. The **[`ROLL_ANGLE`](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/landsat_dictionary.html#roll_angle)** field indicates the corresponding satellite zenith angle.   *(See the [Landsat Data Dictionary](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/landsat_dictionary.html) for a brief explanation of each metadata field.)*

A typical nadir Landsat-8 OLI/TIRS scene would have metadata like:

```
NADIR_OFFNADIR = "NADIR"
ROLL_ANGLE = -0.001
```

---

### Satellite Azimuth

I am not aware of a metadata field for satellite azimuth. You could either use the `CORNER_` X / Y coordinates (or latitude / longitude respectively)   (inside the *_MTL.txt* file) to calculate its azimuth.

Alternatively, you could utilize the WRS (Worldwide Reference System) information (metadata fields `WRS_PATH` and `WRS_ROW`; for landsat 4 onwards, it is sort of a grid indicating where the satellite is on its orbit). Have a look at the [USGS page with has WRS specification documents and shapefile downloads](https://landsat.usgs.gov/worldwide_reference_system_WRS.php), it is basically straightforward.

However, if you are comparing scenes from the *same area*, the satellite's azimuth angle is *not subject to any change*.

*(Note that [Landsat Metadata has changed a little bit](http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat_Metadata_Changes.php) as of August 2012.)*