# Calculating Satellite Azimuth from Landsat WRS data?

Tags: landsat, satellite, azimuth

I found [the below answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91073/81764) in regards to how one identifies the satellite azimuth from Landsat Images, but am not sure how you translate the path/row into azimuth angle. I have searched for such, but am struggling to find an answer, therefore I repost in the hope that someone might be able to advise...

> Alternatively, you could utilize the WRS (Worldwide Reference System) information (metadata fields WRS_PATH and WRS_ROW; for landsat 4 onwards, it is sort of a grid indicating where the satellite is on its orbit). Have a look at the USGS page with has WRS specification documents and shapefile downloads, it is basically straightforward.
>
> However, if you are comparing scenes from the same area, the satellite's azimuth angle is not subject to any change.
>
> (Note that Landsat Metadata has changed a little bit as of August 2012.)